# Win API to change keyboard language programmatically in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard

I want to change the input language in Windows7  programmatically.

I have been used `LoadKeyboardLayout` and `ActivateKeyboardLayout`,

try to change my keyboard language, but it only work on Windows XP

Is there any other API to suport that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that functions not work at Windows 7 ?

Comment: I tried those two functions at Windows 7 and Windows XP ,

Comment: This is not answer for my question.

Comment: Sorry , I don't know why my comment look like that...
I tried those two functions at Windows 7 and Windows XP ,and both return right result, but the keyboard layout didn't change at Windows 7, and I also tried to use "Text Service Framework", and the result was same as LoadKeyboardLayout and ActivateKeyboardLayout.

Comment: Please, add your code.